# How to prevent Monkey test from pressing the home button?

Tags: android, monkey-testing

I am running **Monkey test** on my android app, is there any way to prevent it from pressing the home button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use [screen pinning](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138) to force the Monkey to stay within your app.  Just pin your app to the screen before starting testing.